# Prevent Drupal to go into all modules

Tags: 7

I've 3 modules which implement the form alter beccause I need a new field with a different value function of the module (partner, beneficiary, collectivity)
My issue is, the field value take the value from the last module visited.

For example, on the page /beneficiary, I would like my login form with the profil value as "BENEFICIARY" but I have the "PARTNERS" value instead beacause it's the last visited.

All my 3 form_alter() methods are the same (except the function name of course :) )

```
function partners_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_block':
      $form['profile'] = array(
        '#type'             => 'textfield',
        '#title'            => t('type'),
        '#value'            => 'PARTNERS',
        '#required'         => True,
      );
      break;
  }
}
```

How can i prevent Drupal to parse all modules or do you have an idea on how to implements ?

Comment: why are you going for three form_alter ?

Comment: your need is if the page is in (/partner, /beneficiary, /collectivity) you need that value in the profile field right:)

Comment: yes, but i don't want to test the url value because it can change. @DEVARAJJOHNSON, I have to because these 3 modules can work as standalone or together.

Comment: '#value'=>$_GET[q],

Comment: again @Nabil I don't want to test the url.

Comment: I dont think you can enable and disable a module depending on the url.

Comment: so you want to set a flag for user logging to check the (/partner, /beneficiary, /collectivity) pages ?

Comment: yes @DEVARAJJOHNSON it's the idea behind :)